# How can I get Visual Studio 2010 to refresh the "Latest" status of a locally deleted file

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm new to TFS & VS2010, but I don't seem to be able to find an answer to this question anywhere...

I have previously checked out word documents from VS2010, made changes, checked them back in, and then deleted the local copy on my machine.

How can I get VS2010 to realise it's no longer on my machine? It always says I have the latest version even though it's deleted.

I know there is a VersionControl.config file in C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXX\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0\Cache, but I'm slightly unsure of deleting it.

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to force a sync in the VS IDE, but you can try using tf.exe (it will be on the %path% from a VS command prompt) and use the /force flag, e.g.

```
c:\foo> tf.exe get MissingFile.cs /force
c:\foo> tf.exe get MissingDirectory /r /force
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Get Specific Version Command" with the "Overwrite all.." option checked
More details at this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dstfs/archive/2012/04/26/what-to-do-if-you-delete-files-or-folders-outside-team-explorer-visual-studio-2010-from-your-local-folder.aspx)